# Wordpress htaccess redirect destroys my non-www to www redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, wordpress, directory

In my root domain I have an .htaccess **to redirect non-www to the www, and to redirect to a subdirectory** (containing a temporary website). This is done using the following code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# non-www to www, exclude localhost
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# temp redir to subdir-wordpress
RewriteRule ^$ /subdir [L]
```

In the subdirectory runs a Wordpress setup using the following .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subdir/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /subdir/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

What happens is that people get redirected to `http://domain.com/subdir`, while I want them to end up at `http://www.domain.com/subdir`. I tested with curl and noticed that it redirects with these steps:

1. domain.com => www.domain.com
2. www.domain.com => www.domain.com/subdir
3. www.domain.com/subdir => domain.com/subdir

So the .htaccess in the root dir seems to work fine. But the automated Wordpress .htaccess seems to destroy my hard work :-)

Anyone knows how I can modify the Wordpress .htaccess so it does work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not the Wordpress .htaccess but the Wordpress blog url.

Log into your Wordpress Admin and then goto Settings->General and change your Wordpress URL to www.domain.com/subdir

Comment: This might indeed be the case

Comment: Thanks! Changing this solved the troublesome redirect indeed.